# New iPhone SE (2020) initialized directly from old iPhone SE (2016) gives sync error -50

Tags: iphone, error

There is a related question, but it's very old and none of its answers work: [iPhone backup or sync issue "unknown error occurred (-50)"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148178/iphone-backup-or-sync-issue-unknown-error-occurred-50)

I was getting this error on my old iPhone SE. When I got the new one, I transferred the data from the old iPhone to the new one (directly via WiFi without going through iTunes), and now I get the same error on the new one. Must be related to something installed on it, but I have no idea what or how to look for it. I tried the other answer's thing about looking for dummy apps, didn't find any.

Funny thing is, I get this error when it goes through the sync process, but the sync seems to proceed anyway. The backup is complete, and all the music/photos seem to sync fine.

Comment: I still have this problem.